# Saving record with multiple relations of has_many and belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am unsure of the best way to word this or the terms to use but I am trying to save to a join table the correct way. 
I want to be able to create a new team with a player associated to that team as well as the team be associated with a tournament. My models are as follows:

**tournament.rb**

```
class Tournament < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_players
  has_many :teams, through: :team_players
  has_many :users, through: :team_players
end
```

**team_player.rb**

```
class TeamPlayer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tournament
end
```

**team.rb**

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_players
  has_many :users, through: :team_players
  has_many :tournaments, through: :team_players
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_players
  has_many :tournaments, through: :team_players
  has_many :teams, through: :team_players
end
```

Here is what I am currently trying but getting the below error because it obviously needs a user as well but I dont know how to pass it the current_user.

**tournaments_controller.rb**

```
@tournament.teams.new(name: tournament_params[:new_team_name])
@tournament.save!
```

**Error**: Validation failed: User must exist

Comment: Don't tou have a `Team` model?

Comment: @MatayoshiMariano oops, I forgot to post it. It is added now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BluGeni, you can use [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) in your models. This will make it easier create a `Tournament` while creating a `Team` and assigning an `User` to the `Team`.

Here is an example `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :photos

  accept_nested_attributes_for :photos
end

class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

# Initializing an User and the Photo associated to the user
user = User.new(photos_attributes: { some_attribute: "a value" } )
user.save # Create the User and the Photo

# Creating an User and the photo associated to the user
User.create(photos_attributes: { some_attribute: "a value" } )
```

Comment: So how do get this same result more cleanly than doing: `TeamPlayer.new(tournament_id: @tournament.id, user_id: current_user.id, team_id: team.id)`

Comment: @BluGeni, in this case you cant because you alredy had created the tournament, the user and the team. In the question you mention another problem, regarding the creation of a team and the assignation of the team to a tournament

Comment: Although, you can do `@tournament.update(team_players_attributes: [{user_id: current_user.id, team_id: team.id}])`